How to set a formatter for file handler that will replace unwanted characters?
I have python logger set, which has 2 handlers - 1 for stdout, 1 for file.
Some of the logs i have, contains ANSI Escape characters for colorizing logs in stdout, e.g.
SomeExampleText.... [32mPASS[0m....

I would like to utilize solution in following thread:
How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python
In order to adjust my logger, to strip out the "color" related characters,
But only when logging into fileHandler -
Keep the stdout colored, but my log file without any color related characters.
How can I achieve that?

Related: Printing to STDOUT and log file while removing ANSI color codes and Remove ANSI Escape codes from logging message to file

@wjandrea thanks! per your references i was able to compose solution. many thanks

Per @wjandrea references in comment:

Related: Printing to STDOUT and log file while removing ANSI color codes and Remove ANSI Escape codes from logging message to file

the solution revised is as follows - which works great.
_default_fmt = '[%(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d][%(levelname)s][%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
_default_datefmt = '%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
formatter = logging.Formatter(_default_fmt, _default_datefmt)
sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
sh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(sh)

class FileNoAnsiLogFormat(logging.Formatter):
    _ansi_escape_regex = re.compile(r'\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')

    def format(self, record):
        return self._ansi_escape_regex.sub('', super().format(record))

handler = logging.FileHandler(file_name, mode=file_mode)
handler.setLevel(level)
handler.setFormatter(FileNoAnsiLogFormat(_default_fmt, _default_datefmt))
logger.addHandler(handler)


Please include the link(s) in your answer. It's important to provide attribution, and comments can be deleted for a variety of reasons.

@wjandrea sure, done
